# how do I remove an image from a list in pygame whenever the created avatar collides with a created hitbox?

Tags: pygame

I am trying to make a version of crossy road in pygame, and have figured out the hitboxes for the cars and coins; however, I am trying to make it so whenever the avatar collides with a coin it disappears or somehow loses its effect to add a point to the users score.

```
def pick_up_coin(self, coin):
    coin_hitbox = pygame.Rect(self.avatar.x, self.avatar.y,
                              self.avatar.image.get_width(), self.avatar.image.get_height())
    return coin_hitbox.colliderect(coin.x, coin.y, self.coin.image.get_width(), self.coin.image.get_height())

for j in range(len(self.coins)):
    if self.pick_up_coin(self.coins[j]):
        print("Score") and self.coins[j].kill()
```

Comment: the return value of `print` is `None`. So `self.coins[j].kill()` is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the strange `and` operation:

> ```py
> print("Score") and self.coins[j].kill()
> ```

The return value of `print` is `None` (for `A and B` the `B` term is only evaluated if `A` evaluates to true). So `self.coins[j].kill()` is never executed. You have to write the code in 2 lines:

```py
print("Score")
self.coins[j].kill()
```

Note the `or` instead of `and` would actually work.